# Delphi connecting to NodeJs with websockets

Tags: node.js, delphi, websocket, socket.io

I'm using the websocket library found at https://github.com/andremussche/DelphiWebsockets to connect my delphi application to a NodeJs application written using "socket.io"
But all I get is a "http/1.1 400 Bad Request" message.
Code snippet on delphi side :

```
  fWebSocketClient:=TIdHTTPWebsocketClient.Create(Self);
  fWebSocketClient.Port:=8080;
  fWebSocketClient.Host:='localhost';
  fWebSocketClient.SocketIOCompatible:=true;
  fWebSocketClient.ProtocolVersion:=TIdHTTPProtocolVersion.pv1_1;
  fWebSocketClient.SocketIO.OnEvent(...
  fWebSocketClient.Connect;
```

My nodeJs application works well when tested with Chrome for simple tests messages.
Code snippet for NodeJs :

```
var vhttpModule = require("http");
var socketIO = require('../../../NodeJs/node_modules/socket.io');
var vHttpServer=vhttpModule.createServer(...

vSocket_Io=socketIO.listen(vHttpServer,{});
vSocket_Io.sockets.on(
'connection',function(socket...
```

Any suggestions, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the socket.io protocol is changed in the meantime, maybe you can sniff the data that is send with Chrome and compare it with the one my version sends?

Comment: I finally used SgcWebSockets components. sgcWebSockets (acting as a client) worked with socket.io in mode "api1".  Neverless when I wanted to create a delphi socket server, I add to use the "ws.js" on the NodeJs side  to connect to the delphi socket Server.